# Producing a binary string that has maximum distance to a set of binary strings

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have a set of $d$-length binary strings $S = \{0,1\}^{k\times d}$. How can construct a new string of $d$-length so that the minimum hamming distance w.r.t. the strings in $S$ is maximized?

Comment: Does $S$ have any special structure, e.g. is it a linear code?

Comment: No structures. Maybe the assumption that $2^d >> k$.